# SQL statement to get the difference between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, difference

I have a query which basically is grouping the total sum by day

```
SELECT CountDate, SUM(Max_Count) as MaximumCount, SUM(Min_Count) as MinimumCount
FROM countTable
WHERE countId IN ('48', '34', '65', '63', '31', '64', '86') 
AND CountDate BETWEEN '2014-08-14' AND '2014-08-16' 
GROUP BY CountDate 
ORDER BY CountDate
```

The output result will be

```
 Date       | Maximum   |  Minimum
------------|-----------|----------------------
2014-08-14  |  3018234  |  3014212
2014-08-15  |  3023049  |  3018510
2014-08-16  |  3026813  |  3023244
```

I want the query to get the difference between the MaximumCount of the last day and the MinimumCount of the first day.

The result of the query should be the maximum of the last day i.e. 2014-08-16  :  3026813  minus (-) the minimum of the first day i.e. 2014-08-14  |  3014212. Therefore 3026813 - 3014212

Any help how I could achieve this will be much appreciated.

Comment: how does this single calculation get presented in that result? (i.e. what is the expected output when this new calculation is included?)

Comment: I will only need a single calculation result

Comment: Basically I only want to show the result of the difference of the maximum of the last day and the minimum of the first day

Comment: What version of database you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to Jithin Shaji answer, I've got the result by this query

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = '2014-08-14'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE = '2014-08-16'
DECLARE @NOOFDAYS INT = datediff(day, @STARTDATE, @ENDDATE)

 SELECT  A.CountDate,
    A.MaximumCount - B.MinimumCount AS CountSum
 FROM    (
 SELECT  CountDate, 
    SUM(Max_Count) AS MaximumCount, 
    SUM(Min_Count) AS MinimumCount
 FROM    countTable
 WHERE   countId IN ('48','34','65','63','31','64','86') 
 AND     CountDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND  @ENDDATE
 GROUP   BY CountDate) A
 LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, @NOOFDAYS, CountDate) AS CountDate,
    SUM(Max_Count) AS MaximumCount, 
    SUM(Min_Count) AS MinimumCount
 FROM    countTable
 WHERE   countId IN ('48','34','65','63','31','64','86') 
 AND     CountDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND @ENDDATE 
 GROUP   BY DATEADD(DAY, @NOOFDAYS, CountDate)) B

 ON      A.CountDate = B.CountDate
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT [Maximum] FROM TABLE WHERE Date = (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM TABLE)) -
 (SELECT [Minimum] FROM TABLE WHERE Date = (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM TABLE))
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Philip. Can I do this with the first query, i.e. I have only one query to achieve the result

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be correct.

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATE = '2014-08-14'
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATE = '2014-08-16'

SELECT  A.CountDate,
        B.MaximumCount - A.MinimumCount
FROM    (
SELECT  CountDate, 
        SUM(Max_Count) AS MaximumCount, 
        SUM(Min_Count) AS MinimumCount,
FROM    countTable
WHERE   countId IN ('48','34','65','63','31','64','86') 
AND     CountDate BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND  @ENDDATE
GROUP   BY CountDate) A
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,CountDate,1) CountDate
        SUM(Max_Count) AS MaximumCount, 
        SUM(Min_Count) AS MinimumCount,
FROM    countTable
WHERE   countId IN ('48','34','65','63','31','64','86') 
AND     CountDate BETWEEN BETWEEN @STARTDATE AND  @ENDDATE 
GROUP   BY DATEADD(DAY,CountDate,1)) B

ON      A.CountDate = B.CountDate
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the result given by this query is not the one I want. The result of the query should be the maximum of the last day i.e. 2014-08-16  :  3026813  minus (-) the minimum of the first day i.e. 2014-08-14  |  3014212. Therefore 3026813 - 3014212